# How to modify the SOAP header information for client IP address, while calling SOAP service

Tags: soap, service, web

I have a SOAP server and multiple REST client application.
REST client application, internally Call the SOAP service using WSDL.

when we call the SOAP server it identifies the client on the basis of IP address in the SOAP Header.
I want to implement a mechanism, so that the SOAP sever cannot identify the client IP address and it appears that all the requests are coming from that same IP.

Can we modify this header at client end ? if yes please provide me some solution.....

thanks in advance